# Document elements hidden from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

In a web application I am currently working on, I came across something that seems quirky dealing with javascript document visibility. In this application, I have a div that contains a InfoVis graph representing a network of nodes and edges, and I implementing drag-zoom functionality for it. If you are unfamiliar with it (which is likely), InfoVis is a js library that renders graphs and other visualizations into HTML5 canvases.

I have made a lot of modifications to the core .js of InfoVis to customize appearance and functionality, and that is where I had planned to implement the drag-zoom.

The .html page I am working on loads both the InfoVis core and its own .js file with `<script../>` tags.

In the InfoVis core, defining `onMouseDown: function(e) { alert("click"); }` for the canvas background works as expected, however, when it comes to altering the div (instantiated in the actual .html file and styled in a .css file) like this:

```
onMouseDown: function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  dragging = true;
  $("#dragZoom")[0].style = "display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; left: "+e.clientX+"; top: "+e.clientY+";";
}
```

to set the new style of the div, `$("#dragZoom")` is undefined at `[0]`. In other words, the javscript block can't see the div within the document.

However, if I define a function `function foo() { alert($("#dragZoom")[0]); }` in the other .js file (not the InfoVis core), I can call foo() like this

```
onMouseDown: function(e) {
  foo();
}
```

and foo() can access the div!

Why is this visible from one .js file and not another when they are both being loaded the same way..? This isn't holding me back from accomplishing anything, but I thought it was pretty strange and wanted to find out what was going on. Thanks for any info!

Comment: $("#dragZoom") should not need [0]

Comment: Why not? Doesn't it return the set of all matches? And if I only need the first (only) element, shouldn't I just do that?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, therefore there should never be more than one.

Comment: Right, but the $(string) function in jquery always returns a set. Doing $(".class") returns all elements of class name "class".